# HIgh CPU usage from System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a windows service that after some times of running it takes more then 90% of cpu usage on the server.
I've run the profiles from Visual Studio to have a report of the CPU usage.
The result is that is this

System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()  470789 (92.43%) 470789 (92.43%) mscorlib.ni

The call stack bring me to a Timer_elapsed event where there calls to a logger and 3 thread apart methods.
This is the time elapsed function

```
private void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            logoperazioni?.Save();
            StartPerSecRThread();
            StartPerSecWThread();
            StartBulkThread();
        }
```

The CPU load happen in Debug and in Release mode.

The StartPerSecRThread, StartPerSecWThread and StartBulkThread are method that execute some works using separated thread and are not started if the previous thread is still running. These threads are executing hard works on database only a few times a day. Most of the times are called and the thread starts and ends immediatly. Also in these moments of 'no work', the cpu load is very high.

The timer_elapsed is called every 60 seconds.

Has a temporary workaround I've setup an automatic restart of the service every 6 hours.

I would like to understand why these call are causing all this CPU usage. I'm calling the method without async verb so should run syncronously, right?

Comment: Use a logging Framework. This is just one of the reasons why you should. That out of the way: Are you running the DEBUG-Version of the Service? Those `Logger` calls will only be in the executable if compiled in "Debug" mode.

Comment: My guess is that the logging function takes so long that by the time it's done, it's almost time to run it again.

Comment: You are also not awaiting the result of the logging, so there might even be an exception getting swallowed

Comment: Dig in further with the profiling data. How much time is spent in Logger.LogToFile? How much in StartPerSecRThread? How much in StartPerSecWThread? How much in StartBulkThread? Do all four add together to match the total running time of myTimer_Elapsed? How many times per second is myTimer_Elapsed running? How much time does it take per execution?

Comment: If it also happens in Release build, why do you show us code that is not relevant? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to create a minimal reproducible example, because of the complexity of  the three threaded methods. I've removed the not relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the cause of High CPU Load.

Like suggested by Charlieface, there was some async function in the Logger that was not waited correctly and when throwing exceptions is causing this abnormal CPU load in the thread.